# Map JSON objects array to strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, api

I'm trying to utilize map function in Google SpreadSheets (Google Script) to get my account coin balances from Bittrex using API. Here is my JSON object:

```
({success:true,
  message:"",
  result:[
      {Currency:"BTC",
       Balance:0.01,
       Available:0.01,
       Pending:0,
       CryptoAddress:null},
      {Currency:"ETH",     
       Balance:1.0,
       Available:1.0,
       Pending:0,
       CryptoAddress:null}
    ]}
})
```

Ideally I would like to populate header row automatically, based on Keys in result and underlying rows using data from each object.
I saw spme solutions how to do that using for each or more complicated way. But I guess this can be done by just mapping. Here is how I mapped top row, but don't know how to map values:

```
var headerRow = Object.keys(json.result[0]);
```

Expected output in Google SpreadSheet is

```
____________________________________________________________    
| Currency | Balance | Available | Pending | CryptoAddress |
|__________________________________________________________|
| BTC      | 0.01    | 0.01      | 0       | null          | 
| ETH      | 1.0     | 1.0       | 0       | null          |
____________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: If you are trying to access the value , try that _json.result[headerRow[0]]_ to get the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fully working example:

```
function getBalances() {
  //Spreadsheet where you store your API key and secret
  var keys = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Keys");
  // Output empty sheet where balances will be written to
  var ex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Exchanges");
  var nonce = 1995932972127042 + new Date().getTime(); 

  var key = keys.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var secret = keys.getRange("C2").getValue();

  var baseUrl = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/';
  var command = "account/getbalances";
  var uri = baseUrl + command + "?apikey=" + key + "&nonce=" + nonce;

  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512,uri,secret);
  signature = signature.map(function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('')

  var headers = {
    "apisign": signature
  }

  var params = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": headers,
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, params);  
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).result;    
  var balances = json.map(function(coin) {   
    return ["Bittrex",coin["Currency"],coin["Balance"]]; 
  }).filter(function(coin) { if (coin[2] !== 0) return coin; });

  var headings = ["Exchange","Currency","Balance"];
  balances.unshift(headings);
  ex.getRange(1, 1, balances.length, balances[0].length).setValues(balances);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following. So you have the key and then you can retrieve the value.

```
Object.keys(json.result[0]).map((val) => { console.log(json.result[0][val])})
```

Wrap that within a foreach to do the same for each result.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thx for the tip, but Google Apps Script doesn't support "=>", so I had to spend some time to write it other way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a solution, but here is another way.

```
var row = 1;
json.forEach(function(element,index){
   row = ++row;
   Object.keys(json[index]).forEach(function(e,i)
   {
     ++i;
     if(index == 0) { 
       ex.getRange(1, i).setValue(e);
     }
     ex.getRange(row , i).setValue(element[e]);

  });
});
```